# Can I simultaneously declare and assign a variable in VBA?

Tags: vba, variable-declaration

Can I convert the following declaration and assignment into one line:

```
Dim clientToTest As String
clientToTest = clientsToTest(i)
```

or

```
Dim clientString As Variant
clientString = Split(clientToTest)
```

Answer (score 293, accepted):

There is no shorthand in VBA unfortunately, The closest you will get is a purely visual thing using the `:` continuation character if you want it on one line for readability;

```
Dim clientToTest As String:  clientToTest = clientsToTest(i)
Dim clientString As Variant: clientString = Split(clientToTest)
```

---

Hint (summary of other answers/comments): Works with objects too (Excel 2010):

```
Dim ws  As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As New Worksheet: ws2.Name = "test"
```

Comment: +1, I remember Microsoft suggesting during the buildup to .NET that VB6 developers start doing this to get ourselves ready for VB.NET.

Comment: This is my biggest single complaint about VBA; I bet it would take a junior programmer only a day to add this shortcut to VBA if management cared to add it.

Comment: In MS Access 2003, this one line assignment gives me an 'Out of Memory' error.

Answer (score 26):

You can sort-of do that with objects, as in the following.

```
Dim w As New Widget
```

But not with strings or variants.

Comment: This is not correct, as a whole.  You can declare and initialize a variable on the same line with any data-type (value or object), by simply seperating the "action" with the semi-colo `:`.  There are some limitations as you can not have multiple value declarations on the same line (ie `var1 = val1: var2 = val2`).  It will bug out speradically and allow you to do this type of assignment sometimes but as a whole not suggested by this notation.

Comment: @GoldBishop, yes, using the colon to combine multiple statements into a single line generally works (as Alex K. said). What I'm saying won't work with strings or variants (or probably with other primitives either) is the `Dim x As New T` syntax, which only works with objects.

Comment: yeah wont work on a Constructor Initialization line but it will work with Variant and String assignments.  I use it all the time for Value Types and some Object Types. `dim str as String: str = "value"` and `dim str as Worksheet: set str = ActiveWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")` both work repeatedly.  Although, if i do an Object instantiation `dim ws as New Worksheet: set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` would error out like a any other invalid operation in VBA.

Comment: The colon trick works with variant and string assignments. The `New` keyword doesn't. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @JohnMGrant might want to clarify your answer, as i read it, states: that you cant do same-line assignment with constructor initialization and string/variant value types.  Might be a little confusing to some.

Comment: @JohnMGant, @GoldBishop: `dim ws as New Worksheet: set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` works in Excel 2010! So `New` causes no issues there. (of course it does not make much sense to initialize something that will be overridden immediately again)

Comment: @AndreasDietrich good observation on both points. It does work, but no reason to do it that I can think of (haven't done VBA in 10+ years, though). The key takeaway from all this, I think, is that the colon simply allows you to combine two statements on one line. The colon is syntactically equivalent to the line feed in that usage. May help readability in a few cases, but I think it was generally frowned upon to code that way.

Comment: @AndreasDietrich...who ever said VBA made sense? :)  I ran away from VB5/6 as soon as .Net came out cause of the crazy syntax patterns to perform relative simple actions for VBA/5/6

Answer (score 3):

in fact, you can, but not that way.

```
Sub MySub( Optional Byval Counter as Long=1 , Optional Byval Events as Boolean= True)

'code...

End Sub
```

And you can set the variables differently when calling the sub, or let them at their default values.

Comment: This is for arguments, not local variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can define and assign a value in one line, as shown below.  I have given an example of two variables declared and assigned in a single line. If the data type of multiple variables are the same:

```
Dim recordStart, recordEnd As Integer: recordStart = 935: recordEnd = 946
```

Comment: `recordStart` has type `Variant` here before the assignment, not `Integer`. Explicitly-specified data types only apply to one variable at a time in a `Dim` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the whole need for declaring a variable can be avoided by using [`With` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement).

For example,

```
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    If fd.Show Then
        'use fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
```

this can be rewritten as

```
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
      If .Show Then
        'use .SelectedItems(1)
      End If
    End With
```