# Excel VBA Variable value Scope - assign value to a variable for all subs

Tags: excel, vba, scope, assign

I am writing a module with several subs, and I need some variables to have the same value in all the modules. I know about declaring variables as

```
Public varname as vartype
```

but how can I assign a global value to such a variable?

Thanks

Comment: Put it at the top of any module sheet just below `Option Explicit` and it will be available to all subs in all module and worksheet code pages. This is known as the **Declarations** area.

Comment: @Jeeped I am not talking about declaring the variable, I want to assign a value to it, a value that I want to use all throughout the module; something like a "Public" value; apparently, this is not possible outside a sub

Comment: Assign a value as you would normally, in any sub or even a function. If the value to be assigned is static then the var can be declared as a constant; e.g. `public const csURL as string = "http://stackoverflow.com/"` but you will not be able to change it.

Comment: Creating a public variable and assigning a value is definitely possible. I have a feeling you're forgetting to provide some information.

Comment: You need to tell us what **data type** you're trying to use for your "global" variable in order to get a complete answer.

Comment: @MacroMan it is a worksheet type, if that is of any help; I want to set a certain worksheet ("Sheet1") as a variable to be used in all Subs. Not sure why I got the downvote...

Comment: @horace_vr I didn't downvote so don't know - basically, you can't declare an object in this way (see here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536519/declare-a-workbook-as-a-global-variable/32251725#32251725 so your only option is to assign a value from an event.

Comment: I am trying to avoid writing codes in events, for now. I ended up this this, which seems to be doing the trick: define it as public, assign the value in a "Settings" sub, then call the Settings sub as the very first line in the Main sub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a worksheet object (any object for that matter) you need to do the following:

In a standard code module:

```
Public varName As Excel.Worksheet
```

In the `Workbook_Open()` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set varName = Sheets("mySheet")
End Sub
```

Then you can refer to `varName` in any other module for that workbook and it will point to your worksheet object.

---

From your question/comments, it seems that you actually want some sort of object constant, which can't be done in VBA - see [Declare a Workbook as a Global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536519/declare-a-workbook-as-a-global-variable/32251725#32251725) for more infromation.

If you're referring to a *value* data type such as `String`, `Integer` or `Long` then you can use a constant instead of a variable, however a constant's value cannot be changed once it has been declared (kind of the definition of 'constant') i.e.

```
Public Const someName As String = "Macro Man"
Public Const someNumber As Long = "1234567890"
Public Const someInt As Integer = "1453"
```