# Global HTML-Body of an E-Mail created in a VBA code

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I have the following VBA code for an E-Mail:

```
Sub Global_Email_Message()
Content = "<style> p {background-color: #d9d9d9} </style><p> This message should be global so I can use it in every sub for an E-Mail </p>"
        If ExitAll = False Then
            Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OMail
            .display
            End With
            signature = OMail.HTMLBody
            With OMail
            .To = "test@test.de"
            .Subject = "test"
            .HTMLBody = Content
            End With
            Set OMail = Nothing
            Set OApp = Nothing
        Else
        End If
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly.

Now, I want to achieve that the *message* **and** the *style* in the variable "Content" is global so I can use it in different E-Mail-Subs. How can I globalize the "Content" variable for different E-Mail-Subs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the content variable with public outside the function:

```
Public content as String

Sub Global_Email_Message()
...
```

Comment: I put: Public content As String
content = "<style> p {background-color: #d9d9d9} </style><p> This message should be global so I can use it in every sub for an E-Mail </p>" and deleted the content variable from the Sub Global_Email_Message() but now it does not show any content in the E-Mail.

Comment: You still need to initialise the variable once in a sub/function before it becomes publically available. So I usually have an init_vars sub at the start of my code which I call at the entry point to the application.  Only constants can be declared statically.  And a string cannot be set as a constant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897832/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-public-variable-in-vba-and-assign-a-default-value