# Save an Excel cell to a file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save the contents of a cell to an xml file named by another cell.

I need to perform this check for every row in the sheet.

```
Sub FormatRange()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:AG686")

    For Each row In rng.Rows


    Next row

End Sub
```

For each row I need to save cell `AG` to `xml` file named after cell `C` in the same row.

I am guessing I can use StreamWriter to write the file. I think the real problem is referencing the cells I need.

Comment: What you've posted so far is a random excerpt from a totally different topic, and has absolutely nothing with what you've asked here. Please make a valid effort to solve the problem yourself, and then if you run into problems you can post **your** code here and ask a specific question about it. Just grabbing VBA code from another question is not an actual effort to solve the problem first.

Comment: If you're using 2007+, xlsx files are Open XML, which you can unzip.  Inside the xl folder is a worksheets subfolder that already has the xml you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Sub FormatRange()

 Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:AG686")

' Declare a FileSystemObject.
Dim fso As FileSystemObject

' Create a FileSystemObject.
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
' Declare a TextStream.
Dim stream As TextStream

' Create a TextStream.

For Each row In rng.Rows
        Dim path As String
        path = "C:\vba\" & row.Cells(1, 4) & ".xml"
       ' MsgBox (path + row.Cells(1, 33))
        Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(path, True)
        stream.Write row.Cells(1, 33)


Next row
stream.Close

End Sub
```

Did it! Clustered my way through. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use VBA? I'm guessing if you know what a StreamWriter is you use C# or another .NET language. If so have a look at EPPlus, you can easily loop through your Excel sheet and use the .NET Framework.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, I can use c# but when i get to work i dont have access to c#, only vba. The xml will not have the info im looking for, because the xml is for a different program alltogether, ive created the xml information in a cell by linking together other cells with the required xml and other cells containing the address/name info etc in other cells.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my flexible solution with right-click action and file choosing dialog:

```
Public Sub CellSaver()
    Dim cell
    For Each cell In Application.Selection.Cells
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
          .Title = "Please select the file to save cell contents"
          If .Show Then
            With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(.SelectedItems(1), True)
                .Write cell
                .Close
            End With
          End If
        End With
    Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
        .Caption = "Save to file"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "'CellSaver'"
    End With
End Sub
```

Credits go to:

- @JMG's answer here
- https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4375-excel-add-button-macro-to-right-click-menu.html
- [Can I simultaneously declare and assign a variable in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256122/can-i-simultaneously-declare-and-assign-a-variable-in-vba/55250721#55250721)
- [Excel VBA Cannot call function with onaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064541/excel-vba-cannot-call-function-with-onaction)