# What is wrong with this variable with initial value , Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I dot know why, Excel throws an error at this line:

Dim yearnr As Integer = 18

I want to declare a variable and assign a initial value. Please tell me why it is not working.

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Of This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256122/can-i-simultaneously-declare-and-assign-a-variable-in-vba)

Comment: Could you ... add.. the error message?

Comment: When you say the answers offered below "didn't work" please indicate what happens. Is there an error message? Etc.  All of the answers provided are syntactically correct. If they are not working, I suspect you are not implementing them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA the above format is not possible

only constants can be used like this :

```
Const yearnr As Integer = 18
```

you can use

```
Dim yearnr As Integer
yearnr = 18 


Public yearnr As Integer
yearnr = 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't let you initialize values at declaration as they're already initialized to zero. To do what you want just break it up into two lines.

```
Dim yearnr As Integer
yearnr = 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Question in my comment, For you needs it would be:

```
Dim yearnr As Integer:  yearnr = 18
```

you can make it one line with the `:` character

[image]

Comment: @user2703472 Added a ScrenShot of code in action when you say didn't work what happened??