# How do i declare and define a variable of a custom type in one line

Tags: vba, variables, types, declaration, definition

How can i declare and set a custom type in one line.

```
Option Explicit

Type Stackoverflow
    stack As String
    overflow As String
End Type

Sub WorkingExample()
    Dim example As Stackoverflow
    example.stack = "stack"
    example.overflow = "overflow"
    MsgBox (example.stack + example.overflow)
End Sub

Sub NotCompiling()
    Dim example As Stackoverflow = {.stack = "stack", .overflow = "overflow"}
    MsgBox (example.stack + example.overflow)
End Sub
```

In this mini example the `WorkingExample` shows the behavior i want and the `NotCompiling` part shows what i want to write but i am not able to.

Please show how something like this `Dim example As Stackoverflow = {.stack = "stack", .overflow = "overflow"}` can be written as one line.

Comment: [tag:VBA] is not like [tag:VB.NET]. You cannot declare and set variable in one line. The closest you could get is what's discussed in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256122/can-i-simultaneously-declare-and-assign-a-variable-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon is a line ending like a carriage return.

```
Sub WorkingExample():Dim example As Stackoverflow:example.stack = "stack":example.overflow = "overflow":MsgBox (example.stack + example.overflow):End Sub
```

Comment: Be a little careful with these.  I've had occasional unexpected results when trying to use the `:` to end a line.